# Insert ArrayList in to Android SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

HI,

I have array list of geopoints

```
List<GeoPoint> geoPointsArray = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
```

I want to put geoPointsArray array in to SQLite database and then fetch the data back as an array.

If anyone has a solution I would be greatly appreciated.

P.S.

Now I use ContentValues  for insert into array as:

```
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TIME, time);
        db.insert(tableName, null, initialValues);
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to put geoPointsArray array in to SQLite database and then fetch the data back as an
>   array.

Serialize the `GeoPoint` array to JSON and store it in a `TEXT` column.

Comment: Thanks , can  you please give me simple code for converting in to JSON ?

Answer (score 1):

Or different: Because a [`GeoPoint`](http://code.google.com/intl/de/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html) is build out of 2 integers, just store these integers in 2 columns called 'latitudeE6' and 'longitudeE6', which eliminates any overhead like JSON.