# Convert list in to byte[] for storing in SQLite in Android

Tags: android

I have this array declaration:

```
List<GeoPoint> race = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
```

I want to store this array in to SQLite database.

Can some one give me code for converting this array in to byte[] or give me code for  another solution ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert ArrayList in to Android SQLite database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719632/insert-arraylist-in-to-android-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 0):

If your `GeoPoint` is `Serializable` you can use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` plus an `ObjectOutputStream`.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(list);
byte[] result = baos.toByteArray();
oos.close();
```

---

**Resources :**

- [ObjectOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)
- [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)